# Convert website to a SmartPhone App

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, smartphone

I have created a mobile version of a website and tested it thoroughly, it functions the way i want, does everything, now I want to create a app which just embeds the webpage (actually a /app folder on my domain)

I want to create a app which just embeds my page , I am zero in app development as of now.

however, I can do everything required in php , hmtl5,css,jquery

I tried the following :

```
http://appsmakerstore.com/
http://manage.theappbuilder.com/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx
http://mobilecp.conduit.com/app/dashboard
http://www.andromo.com/projects
```

Also saw PhoneGap but invain...

But none seem to do as i want, just embed the page i want.

Incase you want to knw, I want to create a app like 9gag where there is infinite scroll, and the gags keep on updating in a infinite list...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used [this](http://appinventor.mit.edu/), but it advertises that you can simply drag and drop in a WebView component and then link it to your site. Alternatively, you could create native applications for the phones you want and utilize native WebView components ([UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS and [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for Android)

I'm sure that there are tons of tutorials on the web on how to implement each object.

Comment: Phas1c I have got no experience, to learn and do will take a month or so to  be exact perfect with my app. Any other way round ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
[apps geyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/)

It works but you can't have multiple files put together. Just submit it to google play after that.

Comment: I tried that too, but somehow that was the closer i got, but not as i wanted :(

Comment: Im afraid you have to use web view then.