# A cross platform smartphone app that acts like a browser to just display a website

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, cross-platform

I have a website running in full PHP and some Javascript, but now I would like to create a smartphone app for both iOS and Android for this project.

I see with Cordova and Intel XDK, we could convert a website into an app, but the drawback of this is that all of your website files must be .html and you can only communicate with the server via Javascript AJAX and PHP. The whole website we got right now is pretty much in PHP, and converting the whole thing to be .html and .js is not feasible.

We also have looked around for native routes and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17600523/144201 which point us to UIWebView for iOS and WebView for Android, but then we will need to take care of 2 platforms in this case.

Because of this, does anyone know whether there is a cross platforming method that allows us to create an app that acts like a browser that displays a specified website and communicates with the server?

One example of something like this is http://www.thaiairways.com/en_TH/index.page . Our client shows us their website and their iOS app. We see that both are identical, and we could browse around in their iOS app as if we are browsing their normal website. This is as if the app itself is just a browser that shows the website.

But is it possible to do this in a cross platform way?

Comment: Guys, at least, tell me what is wrong when you downvotes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Cordova, and as your app for security reasons won't let you run JS or a web site hosted remotely, embed a full screen browser in your app, and just make the app a shell for it. This can be done with the following plugin:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

However, you'll probably get rejected by Apple reviewers when submitting that to Apple's store, (assuming you want to publish it for the general public,) since just shelling an app is against Apple's guidelines.

Your users probably won't be so happy too if you do that as things that could load quickly as contained in the app such as graphics, HTML and CSS will be delayed until pulled from the site. The site might not also be skinned to use the appropriate iOS-style widgets or Android Material Design style widgets, or things that you'd typically choose to do on an app such as auto-login might not be an option, and so on.

I don't know why you were down-voted but this type of question (perhaps worded differently) is a common one with my clients, so may be it's already been asked here and you can find the answers with a bit of searching.

Really the best solution unfortunately is to bite the bullet and create an API that your app can hit. Your API can be PHP and provide the same data as on your current web site, so if you're lucky, you can lift a lot of that. Your app could be coded using a popular library for widgets such as Ionic but you'd probably want to look at new HTML rather than porting.